# Call GC.Collect before memory hungry unmanaged function?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, unmanaged

My program seems to generate a lot of garbage then it calls an unmanaged dll function which allocates a lot of memory (~500+MB). The unmanaged function usually fails with an out of memory error. However if I call GC.Collect just before calling the unmanaged function, it never fails.

Task Manager shows the memory use climb monotonically then drop dramatically at the GC.Collect call. Without that call, it continues climbing till it fails.

Everything I read says "don't use GC.Collect except special cases". Could this be such a case? The only problem with calling GC.Collect seems to be that it might be slow. I don't care if it's slow so does that mean it's harmless?

Comment: Well, this is kind of a special case. And it's not always/automatically slower. The GC will have to run from time to time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like a valid situation in which you would call `GC.Collect`. You could also try the `GC.AddMemoryPressure` API which is designed to tell the CLR that you are allocating a lot of unmanaged memory in your process, and might influence the GC's decision to perform a collection earlier.

Comment: MSDN says GC.AddMemoryPressure should be used after allocating unmanaged memory which I can't do because the program's already crashed at that stage. Wouldn't using it before allocating the memory be as much a hack as GC.Collect?

Comment: No, I think it would actually make sense to call it before the native allocation in that case.